# Forbidden: Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

Hi i have this folder on my server and it is clients/nannyshareaustralia and im using a codeigniter framework i already set up the config.php in the base url too. And im adding also for the htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|images|js|assets|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /clients/nannyshareaustralia/index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /clients/nannyshareaustralia/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

and when i run it to the browser this is what it goes

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /clients/nannyshareaustralia on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

can someone help me figured this out? Any help is muchly appreciated

Comment: how are you accessing this through a domain or Directory?

Comment: through a domain then directory

Comment: What url are you trying to access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /clients/nannyshareaustralia
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|images|js|assets|css)
....
```

Added a `RewriteBase` rule to your `.htaccess` granting that `mod_rewrite` is enabled on your server.

**note**
If you access the directory like `www.domain.com/clients/nannyshareaustralia` you must add a RewriteBase to the `.htaccess`

But if a url/domain is pointed at the folder `clients/nannyshareaustralia` there is no need for the `RewriteBase`.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this Following code write in your .htaccess file

> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteBase / 
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
> RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
>  </IfModule>